# How to send few files to a "To" recipient, and few files to a "Cc" recipient, using MFMailComposer in iOS?

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my application I have to send a mail to two recipients. One  person is added as a To recipient and another as a CC recipient.

I am attaching two files to the mail; a PDF file, and an Excel file. I desire that the CC recipients receive both files, and the To recipients receive only the PDF file. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

May be u can try sending two emails, one with pdf attached and other with pdf and excel attached, both with same recepients.

I dont know whether there is any other solution, coz I dont see any option in any email clients to attach a file for a particular recepient.